# Secondary Tkinter window wont open until script finished running

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using an interface kit called phidget. I have my application reading data correctly however, I want to display in real time the current data in a tkinter window. But whenever I run the script the data part runs correctly but the secondary tkinter window (data display) will not open until the data part is done. I think this is due to the way event driven code works but what's the work around for this issue?

below is the script I have:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from Phidget22.Devices.DigitalInput import *
import time

count = 0 - 1
count1 = 0 - 1


class Parts:
    # First Screen
    def __init__(one):
        one.root = tk.Tk()

        one.root.geometry("500x350")
        one.root.title("Parts Counter Program")

        one.label = tk.Label(one.root, text="Welcome To Parts Counter", font=('Arial', 20))
        one.label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        one.button1 = tk.Button(one.root, text="Create New Record", font=('Arial', 15), command=one.openNewWindow1)
        one.button1.pack(padx=25, pady=25)
        one.root.mainloop()

    def openNewWindow1(one):
        # Second Screen
        openNewWindow = tkinter.Tk()
        openNewWindow.title("Create New Record")

        Parts_Info_Frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(openNewWindow)
        Parts_Info_Frame.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        Parts_Label = tkinter.Label(Parts_Info_Frame, text=("Parts No."))
        Parts_Label.grid(row=5, column=0)

        Parts_Box = tkinter.Label(Parts_Info_Frame, width=5, height=2, text=count)
        Parts_Box.grid(row=5, column=1)

        Broken_Label = tkinter.Label(Parts_Info_Frame, text=("Broken No."))
        Broken_Label.grid(row=5, column=2)

        Broken_Box = tkinter.Label(Parts_Info_Frame, width=5, height=2, text=count1)
        Broken_Box.grid(row=5, column=3)

        def onDigitalInput0_StateChange(self, state):
            print("State [0]: " + str(state))
            global count
            count += 1
            print(count / 2)

        def onDigitalInput1_StateChange(self, state):
            print("State [1]: " + str(state))
            global count1
            count1 += 1
            print(count1 / 2)

        def main():

            digitalInput0 = DigitalInput()
            digitalInput1 = DigitalInput()

            digitalInput0.setChannel(0)
            digitalInput1.setChannel(1)

            digitalInput0.setOnStateChangeHandler(onDigitalInput0_StateChange)
            digitalInput1.setOnStateChangeHandler(onDigitalInput1_StateChange)

            digitalInput0.openWaitForAttachment(5000)
            digitalInput1.openWaitForAttachment(5000)

            time.sleep(1)

            digitalInput0.close()
            digitalInput1.close()

        main()

Parts()
```

Comment: Change this `openNewWindow = tkinter.Tk()` to `openNewWindow = tkinter.Toplevel()` Remove this `time.sleep(1)`

Comment: Should `.open()` be used instead of `.openWaitForAttachment(...)` (and remove those `.close()` as well)?